# How do I really know when a UIButton has been released?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I'm running into an issue where I have a UIButton in which I want to track press/release events. So I am tacking on to the Touch Down/Touch Up events. Unfortunately, in certain situations this won't track Touch Up events -- for instance, if an Alert pops up.

```
- (IBAction)buttonDown:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)buttonUp:(id)sender;
```

How do I ensure that the view controller is notified when the button goes from pushed/normal state, no matter what the reason?

Comment: The only way I've been able to solve it thus far is to poll for the `button.state` property and respond when it changes back to Normal. This is clearly suboptimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track the touch cancel event as well. That should do it.

<strike>Edit:
Hmmm, what about `UIControlEventAllTouchEvents`? You have to add it programmatically. I'm really surprised cancel didn't do it. You could also try handling `-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` in your UIViewController.</strike>

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(allTouches) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
```

Excellent.

Comment: Nope, that didn't do it either. It usually happens when I pop a UIAlert while the button is held.

Comment: Actually it did, when I realized I had fat-moused the IB wiring :P

Answer (score 3):

Try this method:

```
[myButton addTarget: target action: @selector(buttonUp:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, I do have both Touch Up Inside and Outside hooked up in IB.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to detect if the buttons are being pressed or released while the UIAlert view is currently on top or has it been dismissed and the button presses are no longer responsive?

Comment: Trying to detect if the UIAlert is displayed while the button is depressed (because when this happens, the button goes back to Normal state but does not fire a Touch Up)